# Yii2: How to force using fallback MessageFormatter method?

Tags: php, yii2, internationalization

My website is with a hosting provider that has the MessageFormatter class available on the server (Linux, PHP 7.0.27) but it is an old ICU version (4.2.1) that doesn't support my message `{number,plural,=0{# available} =1{# available} other{# available}}` and gives the error:

> Message pattern is invalid: Constructor failed
>
> msgfmt_create: message formatter creation failed: U_ILLEGAL_CHARACTER

...because of the `=1` and `=2` notation.

I'm not able to make changes to the server so how can I force using the fallback method provided by Yii2 which works just fine?

Comment: do you have `php_intl` extension installed?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Yes, that is the problem. If that old version just wasn't installed it wouldn't be an issue as the fallback method would automatically be used.

Comment: at least `ICU 4.8` should be installed and there is a requirement checking script, Copy `/requirements.php` to `/web/requirements.php` and then use a browser to access it via `http://localhost/requirements.php` or in terminal `php requirements.php` and see what it prints. and there should be more info on the error logs. about this error.

Comment: and in which environment do you have `ICU < 4.8` ? even Debian oldoldstable (wheezy) has `ICU 4.8`.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Looks like my hosting provider is using Red Hat 4.4.7 (from around 2012?), Linux version 2.6.32. `requirements.php` says the same - ICU is too old, and ICU Data is missing. And they don't want to make any changes on the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is this hacky way you can try.

Copy the `yii\i18n\MessageFormatter` code to a new file. Name it `MessageFormatter.php` and place somewhere in your application (but not in `vendor` folder).

In this new file change the `format()` method to:

```
public function format($pattern, $params, $language)
{
    $this->_errorCode = 0;
    $this->_errorMessage = '';

    if ($params === []) {
        return $pattern;
    }

    return $this->fallbackFormat($pattern, $params, $language);
}
```

Don't change anything else (including namespace).

Now let's use Yii mapping.

Find a place in your application when you can put code that will be run every time in [bootstrapping phase](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-bootstrapping.html). Good place for this is `common/config/bootstrap.php` if you are using "Advanced Template"-like project.

Add there this line:

```
Yii::$classMap['yii\i18n\MessageFormatter'] = 'path/to/your/MessageFormatter.php';
```

Obviously change the path to the one you've chosen. Now Yii autoloader will load this class from your file instead of the original Yii vendor folder (as mentioned in [Class Autoloading](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-autoloading.html#class-map) section of the Guide).

In the modified file `MessageFormatter` method presence of `intl` library is never checked so fallback is used as default.

The downside of this trick is that you need to update manually your file every time original Yii file is changed (so almost every time you upgrade Yii version).

---

Another approach is to configure I18N component in your application to use your custom `MessageFormatter` where you can extend the original file and just override `format()` method inside without modifying class map.

Comment: Yes, you can do that but another disadvantage about this approach is fallback doesn't work well with non-default language and has very limited functionality compared to `intl`. otherwise, OP has to either change hosting or persuade them to update.

Comment: OP asked for fallback forcing so I gave him answer.

Comment: yeah i just wanted to add to the answer. so that OP may know all aspects before moving forward.

Comment: Thanks, this even led me to several possible solutions!